# EclipseLink Queries

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Is there a way to create the equivalent behavior provided by EclipseLink’s AdditionalCriteria annotation in JPA? That is, can we create additional filtering that is added to every query for a particular entity type? We can use EclipseLink, but we don’t want to be dependent on it.

Comment: Not directly, no though most providers should have equivalent mechanisms.  What is the nature of your filter, as you might get by with other JPA options that can filter, or use named queries with the filter built in rather than dynamic ones.

Comment: I also have here the class that is giving us the error:

Comment: I also have here the class that is giving us the error, at least the annotation part. I think that should be enough?

Comment: @AdditionalCriteria("( this.toId = :ORG_ID ) OR "
    + "( this.toMemberOrgId = :ORG_ID ) OR "
    + "( this.fromId = :ORG_ID ) OR "
    + "( this.fromMemberOrgId = :ORG_ID ) OR "
    + "( this.relatedDocument.fromId = :ORG_ID AND "
    + "((this.documentType = 'ConfirmationDocument' OR this.documentType = 'ShipNoticeDocument') AND this.relatedDocument.documentType = 'PurchaseOrder') OR (this.documentType = 'CopyRequest') )")
public class ANCXMLDocument implements Serializable

Comment: I have a copy of the entire file shared on OneDrive at:  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A57D9AE3E198F692!107&authkey=!AANn6Hu7gODrwUU&ithint=file%2cjava